# Retrieving command line argument of process at driver level

Tags: windows, device-driver

Hello I am writing a minifilter driver for intercepting all the irp packets from a certain process say a.exe .

So , in the driver code it can be done by applying a check on the command line arguments that started the process.

Does anyone know how can i retrieve the command line argument ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: It sounds like you're making a security decision based on the command line. This will not work because the command line can be edited by the application, so they can spoof it.

Comment: @RaymondChen -- actually i have to process a command line request and based on the arguments passed , it will forward  the request to filter stack downward . Can u elaborate  how spoofing can be done ?

Comment: The application is passed a pointer to a string that describes the parameters. This actually points to the parameter in the PEB. The application can simply alter the page's protection flags and write to that memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no supported way to do this from within kernel-mode. In fact, trying to access user-mode process information from the kernel is a pain in general. I would suggest firing up a request to a user-mode service, which can then find that information and pass it back down to your kernel component.

However, there an undocumented method to do it. If you can get a handle to an [`EPROCESS`](http://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/EPROCESS.html) struct for the target process, you can get at a pointer to the [`PEB`](http://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/PEB.html) (process environment block) struct within it, which then has a pointer to an [`RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`](http://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS.html) structure, which has a member called `CommandLine`.

Example:

```
UNICODE_STRING* commandLine = epProcess->Peb->ProcessParameters->CommandLine;
```

The downside to this is that `EPROCESS` is almost entirely opaque and `PEB` is semi-opaque too, meaning that it may change in future versions of Windows. I certainly wouldn't advocate trying this in production code.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess) or [ZwQueryInformationProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/zwqueryinformationprocess) function with the PROCESSINFOCLASS parameter as ProcessBasicInformation.  The output parameter, ProcessInformation, will be a struct of type PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.  As Polynomial mentioned, this struct has a pointer to the process's [PEB struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb), which contains the information you are looking for in its ProcessParameters field.